# Outlook 2010: automatic category assignment for meetings

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, automation, calendar

I extensively use the calendaring module of Outlook 2010 and I am looking for a way to automatically assign categories to meetings, based on various criteria (participants, attachments, etc.). This is very similar to the "Conditional Formatting" option in View -> View Setting, except that I want to assign a category instead of merely a color.

Ideally the category should be kept in synch with the proprieties of the meeting (ie. when the meeting changes and a condition for a category assignment is met (and was not met before) the categories should update (be added or removed)).

Thank you for any pointers!

Comment: @CharlieRB: I could not find anything out of the box (having looked around Outlook). The closest I got to was to use a Rule (on new email) but this is very limited (only applies to new meetings, is not dynamic upon changes, limited granularity on conditions (pertinent to a meeting - participants for instance)). As I mentioned I am looking for pointers towards a reasonable direction from someone who is more knowledgable than me in Outlook.

Comment: I asked on the basis of improving your question because it does not indicate what you've tried or searched. People who are likely to answer your question have an expectation that you've tried to solve this on your own before asking for help. Doing so, helps you get more complete answers and avoid back and forth dialog finding out in that you've already tried what others answer. Please feel free to [edit] your question to give more details and update what you've found to work or not work.

Comment: @CharlieRB:with all due respect - the question is asked correctly. It states the problem, a sought solution similar to an existing feature in Outlook (as well as some nice-to-have) and asks for a direction to look at. I dod not find anything interesting, otherwise I would have stated it (I am not [Edison](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=747226) to state all that failed :))